# Retrieving the values from input elements and storing in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, dom

I've got a form that takes input from the user

```
<form id='myForm'>
        <div id='x'>
                 <h2> start </h2>
            <ul class="rounded">
                <li><input type="text"  placeholder="text" id="o" /></li>
            </ul>
                <h2>dests </h2>
            <ul class="rounded">
                <li><input type="text"  placeholder="text" id="d" /></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="rounded">
                <li><input type="text"  placeholder="text" id="d" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
<li class="arrow"><a href="#page2" onclick='function()'>Run </a></li>
</form>
```

I need a way of getting the user input from every field in the form, and placing it into an array. I have looked into getElementByTagName('input'), but this returns a HTMLCollection object. Any suggestions? (P.S i'm using a jqtouch if you're wondering what's up with the weird syntax)

Comment: I see you have two input with the same `id`. `id`'s should be unique, also what have you tried so far? Where is your javsascript to go with this?

Comment: You have several elements having the same ID

Comment: As they've mentioned in the comments, you have several controls with the same id. 
You can try the line of codes below.
var inputControls = $('#myForm').find('input[type=text]');
var inputArray = [];

$.each(inputControls, function(index, value){
  var inputValue = $(item).val();
   inputArray.push(inputValue);
});

Comment: Do they have to be unique? The form is dynamic (users can add more dests) so its difficult to increment the id as the users adds more dests.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned be careful to use the html id attribute with a unique id, i.e. each input should have its own.

Using vanilla JavaScript, `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a live [html collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and you can access its members as properties using `[index]` to get the element you want. Then use `textObject.value` to access the inputs' value.

All in all, `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value` will provide the value of the first input! That is the logic, also check the snippet.

Please also consider the following:

- `element.querySelectorAll()` is generally slower than `element.getElementsByTagName()`, as the first uses a depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes
- `element.querySelectorAll()` returns a StaticNodeList

I found this [article](http://ryanmorr.com/abstract-away-the-performance-faults-of-queryselectorall) quite interesting for this topic.

```js
function retrieve(){
  let list = document.getElementById('inputListContainer');
  let input = list.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let array = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
    //input[i].value is the same as document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value
    array.push(input[i].value); 
  }
  console.log( array );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='inputListContainer'>
      <!-- Using a single ul to parent list items. Note that this does not affect the script -->
      <ul id='inputList' class='rounded'>
        <li><input type="text"  placeholder="one"/></li>
        <li><input type="text"  placeholder="two"/></li>
        <li><input type="text"  placeholder="three"/></li>
      </ul>
      <button onclick='retrieve()'>Retrieve</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array from the list of *input* elements obtained from [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Try filling the `input`s and clicking *Run* in the demo below:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm input');

function callme() {
  var result = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(e) {
    return e.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<form id='myForm'>
  <div id='x'>
    <h2> start </h2>
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>dests </h2>
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="arrow"><a href="#page2" onclick='callme()'>Run </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getValues() { 
  var values = []; // Array of input values
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    values.push(elements[i].value);
    //If you need the input ID:
    //values.push({name: elements[i].id , value: elements[i].value});
  }
}
```

Comment: If I were you I would swap `getElementsByTagName('input');` with `document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");` otherwise this will get all inputs from the page. The OP is wanting to get all the inputs from the form.

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks @NewToJS

Comment: Very welcome, your original answer was pretty close so rather than me submitting the same but have a minor change I thought it would be easier to post a comment :) To be honest I would add some information about using `querySelectorAll()` and a working snippet. Seeing the demo and a detailed answer seem to be more valued. If you choose not to update your answer I will be submitting a details one.

Comment: @NewToJS Agree with you. A working snippet with details can be helpful in order to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [**Document.querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Using `document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");` will target all inputs within the form with the `ID` of `myForm`.

Then a [**for()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop is used to iterate through the collection and push the `input` values into the array .

> The for statement creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement (usually a block statement) to be executed in the loop.

`for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement`

```js
function BuildArray() {
  var myArray = [];
  var input = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(input[i].value);
  }
  console.log(myArray);
}
```

```html
<form id='myForm'>
  <div id='x'>
    <h2> start </h2>
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" id="o" value="first" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>dests </h2>
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" id="d" value="second" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li>
        <input type="text" placeholder="text" id="d" value="third" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <li class="arrow"><a href="#page2" onclick='BuildArray()'>Run </a>
  </li>
</form>
```

I would also like to recommend keeping `ID`'s unique if `ID`'s are required but for this task `ID`'s are not used in the selector so no problems if ID's are the same.

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and i will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to iterate through each input and push each value into an array. You would call something like this on click. See jQuery example here.

```
function click() {
   var arr = [];

   $.each($('input'), function(k,v) {
      arr.push($(v).val());
   })

   console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: **jQuery** isn't tagged in this question.